# How is this instance method accessible in another class

Tags: ruby, methods

Here is the code:

```
class Movie

    def initialize(title, rank=0)
        @title = title
        @rank = rank
    end

    def to_s
        "#{@title} has a rank of #{@rank}"
    end

    def thumbs_up
        @rank += 1
    end

    def thumbs_down
        @rank -= 1
    end
end

class Playlist
    def initialize(name)
        @name = name
        @movies = []
    end

    def add_movie(movie)
        @movies << movie
    end

    def play 
        puts "#{@name}'s playlist:"

        @movies.each do |movie|
            movie.thumbs_up
            puts movie
        end
    end
end`
```

My question is regarding thumbs_up. This code is working, but I'm curious as to how thumbs up is accessible within the play method in the Playlist class. Is this because the movie being added to the array is an instance of Movie, and can thus have thumbs_up called on it? If so, its strange that that method can be called within a different class like that.

Thanks.

Comment: But it's a method of "movie" instances. That's kind of the point of instance methods-the ability to call them.

Comment: It's about as strange as being able to call the 'each' method on the array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not that strange.  `thumbs_up` is a public method of objects in the Movie class, so wherever a movie object resides, you can call `thumbs_up` on it.

The method is one of the characteristics of a Movie object, which consists of methods and states (states is the information stored in a class object, in the instance variables).

Answer (score 1):

`thumbs_up` is a `public` method, and as such, can be invoked from the `Movie` instance regardless of where the invokation occurs.